# Can we configure the OWASP ZAP report with mail?

Tags: zap, security-testing

I want to configure the zap report to my mail id so that whenever I generate ZAP report it should send it to my mail. Is is possible to do so?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge, but you can either contribute this feature - or add it to [Glue](https://github.com/OWASP/glue), which make more  sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

[ZAP API](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiDetailsUI) can be used to generate reports in html, xml, json and md format. Once you generate report, you could use mailer service to send reports to your email address.